How to merge headings from user_constraints and user_cons_columns
I am trying to output my constraints using both data dictionary tables. I want the output to include CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME   POSITION   LAST_CHANGE, but I am not sure how to go about it since Position and Column_name are in a different data dictionary table. I am doing this on SqlPlus

The answer may depend on which dictionary items you can access, can you run select * from user_tables fetch first 10 rows only or select * from all_tables fetch first 10 rows  only  look at this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/B4G7FsGe

By the way, you should include the sql query you have tried or attempted (even if imprefect) in the question. There is an edit link for this beneath the question. Also, refer to site Help (link in page footer) on best practices for asking questions at Stackoverflow.

You'll need to perform join.
First, set columns' width so that the nicely fit the screen
SQL> col constraint_name format a15
SQL> col constraint_type format a15
SQL> col table_name format a10
SQL> col column_name format a11
SQL> col last_changed format a15

Stretch line width a little bit:
SQL> set linesize 100

Set date format:
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Finally:
SQL> SELECT c.constraint_name,
  2         c.constraint_type,
  3         c.table_name,
  4         t.column_name,
  5         t.position,
  6         c.last_change
  7    FROM user_constraints c JOIN user_cons_columns t ON t.table_name = c.table_name
  8   WHERE ROWNUM <= 3;

CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME   POSITION LAST_CHANGE
--------------- --------------- ---------- ----------- ---------- -------------------
PK_DEPT         P               DEPT       LOC                  1 15.07.2024 07:07:33
FK_DEP_LOC      R               DEPT       LOC                  1 15.07.2024 07:09:43
FK_EMP_DEPT     R               EMP        DEPTNO               1 15.07.2024 07:07:34

SQL>


If you'll use all_constraints or dba_constraints (and _cons_columns), you'll have to join on owner column as well.
